# Indices in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlite, indexing

There is a table in a Postgres database, and data is being permanently inserted into it. I need a fast access to the data so I create an index for it. I know that it is better to create indices after the most data was already inserted but I don't have such a moment, the data is inserted more or less continuously. When should I create an index on such a table?

There are approximately 40-50 000 inserts per hour, and the data should be kept for several weeks (maybe 2-3 months). No updates, no deletes.

The old implementation in sqlite had a database (a separate file) for every hour but creating indices was taking too much time and the fast access was required almost immediately after insertion (after 5-10 minutes).

Comment: You may be interested in [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html). In this scenario indexes should be created for each partition separately, typically just after a partition is created.

Comment: just create your index and the inserts will keep it up to date, what is the issue?

Comment: That's ~11-14 inserts per second. That's not *so* high that you should worry too much about the impact of the index being updated with the inserts, I wouldn't think, unless your testing proves otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Create a materialized view of the table. Create index on the view, not on the table. Insert into the table and read from the view.

REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW periodically, like every 5 minutes maybe. You may also consider using the CONCURRENTLY parameter.

But in this way your reading does not get the latest updated data. And it's hard to say if the performance characteristics are preferable without trying.